# Pdftex.def Error, Cannot open Ghostscript for piped input: gs

Tags: graphics, errors, pdftex, eps, ghostscript

I can compile my latex document from mac terminal using

```
pdflatex mydocument.tex
```

However, Texshop fails to compile my file. More precisely, Texshop cannot convert `.eps` files to `pdf`file. The minimal code, The Error that Texshop gives, and the log files are below. Can someone help me?

```
Error: Cannot open Ghostscript for piped input: gs -q -dSAFER - dNOPAUSE - dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=fig1-eps-converted-to.pdf -dPDFSETTINGS#/prepress -dMaxSubsetPct=100 -dSubsetFonts=true dEmbedAllFonts=true -dAutoRotatePages#/None - -c quit 

Error: Package pdftex.def Error: file `fig1-eps-converted-to.pdf` not found
```

I add that fig1.eps file is in the same folder that my latex `.tex` file is.

**Minimal code:**

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,color,graphicx, amsbsy}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{booktabs, multicol, multirow}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{.14cm}

\begin{document}

\title{}
\author{}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
{\includegraphics*{fig1.eps}}\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Log File:**

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.5.24)  6 MAR 2016 23:03
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Manuscript.tex
(./Manuscript.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/IEEEtran/IEEEtran.cls
Document Class: IEEEtran 2014/09/17 V1.8a by Michael Shell
-- See the "IEEEtran_HOWTO" manual for usage information.
-- http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenA=\dimen102
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenB=\dimen103
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenC=\dimen104
\@IEEEtrantmpcountA=\count79
\@IEEEtrantmpcountB=\count80
\@IEEEtrantmpcountC=\count81
\@IEEEtrantmptoksA=\toks14
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+ptm on input line 458.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd
File: ot1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.)
-- Using 8.5in x 11in (letter) paper.
-- Using PDF output.
\@IEEEnormalsizeunitybaselineskip=\dimen105
-- This is a 10 point document.
\CLASSINFOnormalsizebaselineskip=\dimen106
\CLASSINFOnormalsizeunitybaselineskip=\dimen107
\IEEEnormaljot=\dimen108
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <5> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1039.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <5> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1039.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <7> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1039.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <7> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1039.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <8> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1039.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <8> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1039.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <9> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1039.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <9> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1039.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1039.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1039.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <11> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1039.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <11> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1039.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1039.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1039.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <17> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1039.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <17> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1039.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <20> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1039.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <20> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1039.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <24> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1039.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <24> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1039.

\IEEEquantizedlength=\dimen109
\IEEEquantizedlengthdiff=\dimen110
\IEEEquantizedtextheightdiff=\dimen111
\IEEEilabelindentA=\dimen112
\IEEEilabelindentB=\dimen113
\IEEEilabelindent=\dimen114
\IEEEelabelindent=\dimen115
\IEEEdlabelindent=\dimen116
\IEEElabelindent=\dimen117
\IEEEiednormlabelsep=\dimen118
\IEEEiedmathlabelsep=\dimen119
\IEEEiedtopsep=\skip41
\c@section=\count82
\c@subsection=\count83
\c@subsubsection=\count84
\c@paragraph=\count85
\c@IEEEsubequation=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip42
\belowcaptionskip=\skip43
\c@figure=\count87
\c@table=\count88
\@IEEEeqnnumcols=\count89
\@IEEEeqncolcnt=\count90
\@IEEEsubeqnnumrollback=\count91
\@IEEEquantizeheightA=\dimen120
\@IEEEquantizeheightB=\dimen121
\@IEEEquantizeheightC=\dimen122
\@IEEEquantizeprevdepth=\dimen123
\@IEEEquantizemultiple=\count92
\@IEEEquantizeboxA=\box26
\@IEEEtmpitemindent=\dimen124
\c@IEEEbiography=\count93
\@IEEEtranrubishbin=\box27) 
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cite/cite.sty
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 302.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nocite on input line 332.
Package: cite 2015/02/27  v 5.5)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfigure/subfigure.sty
Package: subfigure 2002/03/15 v2.1.5 subfigure package
\subfigtopskip=\skip44
\subfigcapskip=\skip45
\subfigcaptopadj=\dimen125
\subfigbottomskip=\skip46
\subfigcapmargin=\dimen126
\subfiglabelskip=\skip47
\c@subfigure=\count94
\c@lofdepth=\count95
\c@subtable=\count96
\c@lotdepth=\count97

****************************************
* Local config file subfigure.cfg used *
****************************************
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfigure/subfigure.cfg)
\subfig@top=\skip48
\subfig@bottom=\skip49)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/epsfig.sty
Package: epsfig 1999/02/16 v1.7a (e)psfig emulation (SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 94.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO))
\Gread@gobject=\count98))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen127
\Gin@req@width=\dimen128)
\epsfxsize=\dimen129
\epsfysize=\dimen130)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/courier.sty
Package: courier 2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (WaS))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\@emptytoks=\toks16
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip50

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0
\@emptytoks=\toks17
\ex@=\dimen131))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d
\pmbraise@=\dimen132)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names)
\inf@bad=\count99
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 210.
\uproot@=\count100
\leftroot@=\count101
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 306.
\classnum@=\count102
\DOTSCASE@=\count103
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 378.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 381.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 466.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box28
\strutbox@=\box29
\big@size=\dimen133
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 566.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 567.
\macc@depth=\count104
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count105
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count106
\dspbrk@lvl=\count107
\tag@help=\toks18
\row@=\count108
\column@=\count109
\maxfields@=\count110
\andhelp@=\toks19
\eqnshift@=\dimen134
\alignsep@=\dimen135
\tagshift@=\dimen136
\tagwidth@=\dimen137
\totwidth@=\dimen138
\lineht@=\dimen139
\@envbody=\toks20
\multlinegap=\skip51
\multlinetaggap=\skip52
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks21
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2665.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2666.)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
Package: color 2014/10/28 v1.1a Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive)
Package color Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 142.)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf.sty
Package: epstopdf 2010/02/09 v2.5 Conversion with epstopdf on the fly (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
Package: grfext 2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.)
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)            [.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 452.

(/usr/local/texli
```

Comment: Do you mind posting the entire log? Plus it us not texshop that converts the eps' try manually compiling using pdflatex in a terminal

Comment: @daleif I uploaded the full log file. I can successfully compile using pdflatex in terminal. So for sure something is wrong with my Texshop. Does a picture from my Texshop setting help?

Comment: Do not add the file extension!

Comment: By the way, updating your operating system implies that you want to be a modern person. Why not updating your LaTeX document a bit? Some of the packages are obsolete for a decade or longer.

Comment: @Johannes_B haha,  actually this is a template that I got  5 years go from a professor. I didn't know that the packages are too old. Do you mind specify which one are old and what alternative can I use?

Comment: @Johannes_B   You mean I should use `{\includegraphics*{fig1}}\end{center}` rather than `{\includegraphics*{fig1}}\end{center}`? But Texshop fails in both cases.

Comment: @Mahdi Please do not get me started n templates. Using the `center` environment within a figure is one strange thing to start with.

Comment: @Johannes Sure, :) I hope I can fix this `.eps` issue.  I would definitely look for a newer template soon.

Comment: @daleif  in my Texshop preference an at Engin tab, in Latex box it is written `pdflatex --file-line-error --synctex=1`   Does this look normal?

Comment: @Mahdi it does, but the test is to rule out issues with the editor, therefore it is a common test to simply compile the doc directly from a terminal without any interaction from an editor. If that gives the same result, we know the editor is not to blame in the issue.

Comment: Texshop also gives me this error `Error: Cannot open Ghostscript for piped input: gs -q -dSAFER - dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=fig1-eps-converted-to.pdf -dPDFSETTINGS#/prepress -dMaxSubsetPct=100 -dSubsetFonts=true dEmbedAllFonts=true -dAutoRotatePages#/None - -c quit `

Comment: Please update your question with that information and perhaps update the title of the question, **that** is very relevant, did you apply the fix that Bruce linked to? I do not remember if there is a gs setting in texshop

Comment: @dalief.  Yes,  the link that Bruce sent me fixes another issue. But `eps` to `pdf` conversion does not work yet with my Texshop.

Comment: Is ghostscript installed? Did you try ghostscript manually in a terminal?

Comment: @Martin running the command `which ghostscript` does not show anything in terminal output.  I tried to run Ghostscript.pkg on my mac, but encountered an error. Do you think the problem is installation of Ghostscript? I note that compiling my document with `pdflatex My_Document.tex` works very well in terminal.

Comment: @Mahdi: It's probably a ghostscript problem. Try to install that properly.

Answer (score 3):

As it is said in the comments, simply installing `ghostscript` through the package manager in the Linux distribution I'm using solved the problem.

Comment: I am using TeX on macOS Catalina, and installing the ghostscript through homebrew works well: `brew install ghostscript` . But first you need to install the homebrew from https://brew.sh/ if you haven't install it.